# Unable to load image to ImageView in Fragment com.nostra13.universalimageloader

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, universal-image-loader

I am trying to load the Image in ImageView using UniversalImageLoader from nostra13 but it does not load (Image is blank) in the Fragment. I see the showImageOnLoading icon but then it disappears and the image is not shown although the image exists on URL. My implementation is as below:

```
package com.rayat.pricewiz.request;

import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoader;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.ImageLoaderConfiguration;
import com.rayat.pricewiz.R;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.display.RoundedBitmapDisplayer;


public class WebImageLoader {
DisplayImageOptions options;
ImageLoader imageLoader;

public WebImageLoader(Context context) {

    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showImageOnLoading( context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_stub) )
            .showImageForEmptyUri(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_empty))
            .showImageOnFail(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_error))
            .cacheInMemory(true)
            .cacheOnDisk(true)
            .considerExifParams(true)
            .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20))
            .build();

    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    if (!imageLoader.isInited()) {
        imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(context));
    }
}

public void displayImage(ImageView imageView,String imageURL) {
    imageLoader.displayImage(imageURL,imageView,options);
}
}
```

And in the fragment, I have this code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.premium_ad_fragment,container,false);
    ImageView imageView = (ImageView)relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgPremiumAd);
    WebImageLoader imageLoader = new WebImageLoader(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    imageLoader.displayImage(imageView,image_url);
    return relativeLayout;
}
```

Any suggestions please.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured out, the image size was not set properly, I changed the `android:layout_width` and `android:layout_height` for the `ImageView` to `match_parent` in my layout resource file and now it appears